# Javascript array nesting

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a module from free code camp that I copied. I was wondering how the values 13 & 14 are called since it’s a nested array. Would you do [3] [1] [0] to call value 13?

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
const arr = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[[10, 11, 12], 13, 14]
];

const subarray = arr[3];
const nestedSubarray = arr[3][0];
const element = arr[3][0][1];
```

This wasn’t covered in the module just trying to understand how arrays work

Comment: The question is about JavaScript arrays - the code sample is not Java programming language syntax.

Comment: A good thing to do in this scenario is to run the code and see what happens by printing the output

Answer (score 2):

> *"... Was wondering how the values 13 & 14 are called since it’s a nested array. Would you do [3] [1] [0] to call value 13? ..."*

No, you would use *[3][1]* for *13* and *[3][2]* for *14*.
The third element of *arr* is *[[10, 11, 12], 13, 14]*, and the first and second elements of this are, *13* and *14*, respectively.

```js
const arr = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[[10, 11, 12], 13, 14]
];

console.log(arr[3][1])
console.log(arr[3][2])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would you do [3] [1] [0] to call value 13?

**No.**  Just `arr[3][1]` is enough to get the value `13`.  And `arr[3][2]` gets you `14`.

You could explore this expression for yourself by logging each part.

```js
const arr = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[[10, 11, 12], 13, 14]
];

console.log(arr); // the outermost array
console.log(arr[3]); // the inner array: [[10, 12,12], 13, 14]
console.log(arr[3][1]); // the number 13
console.log(arr[3][1][0]); // undefined (This is tricky! it's doing: 13[0])
```

###### Why `13[0]` is `undefined`...

In JavaScript, when you try to do property access on a Number using `[]` you'll find that the number `13` is a thing called a *Number instance* which is an *ordinary object* but it doesn't have a property called "0", so it just results in `undefined`.